# how to make a command that only works for a certain role in a certain channel, otherwise it sends them a message to ask for a role

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, nextcord

I'm currently coding a discord bot on the side and I'm stuck on a command that I'm trying to only make certain role to use it, when the wrong role type the command he got a reply to get the right role and I'm wondering how I can mix those 2 commands in 1

thanks for your help, im a noob since i just start coding

```
@commands.has_any_role('Sluts', 'Customer')
@commands.cooldown(1, 17992, commands.BucketType.user)
async def generate(ctx):
  if ctx.message.channel.name == 'Channel_id':
    emoji2 = bot.get_emoji(932456512180338759)
    await ctx.reply('Initialized')
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji2)
    #await main.script()
    await ctx.author.send('DM: Done! Enjoy!')
  else
      await ctx.send('You can not use this command here: checkout #channel_id')

and this line 

@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Leaker', 'Customer')
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def generate(ctx):
   emoji2 = bot.get_emoji(877247467459084298)
   await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji2)
   await ctx.send('You can not use this command here,open a ticket to get the right role')
   await ctx.author.send('DM: ')
```

Comment: hi, not sure if this has some tips https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360045778711-Restrict-bots-to-certain-channels-

Comment: no really because i really want the bot to reply to the wrong command

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not using commands.has_any, because you need to use on_command_error which is not the nicest thing.
You should check if. a certain role is in the author
`if special_user_id in [role.id for role in ctx.author.roles]`

Comment: would this work for the whole role or only specific user with role ?

Comment: anyone that has the role they can have other roles as well